# How to programmatically add menu item

Tags: gatsby

I am creating pages programmatically from markdown files. How can I also add file names as menu items so I could generate menu items programmatically? Why I need it you may ask. I need it because when I add another markdown page using netlifyCMS it should be added to the menu without code modification.
 Is there any easy way provided by Gatsby itself or by any other its plugins. Thank you very much for your time and help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a GraphQL query in your template to get `allMarkdownRemark`.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query CoursesQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark {
      edges {
        node {
          {... what you want}
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

It gives you an array with all your markdown pages.

You retrieve it in your props as usual with the graphQL query.

You must then loop to generate one item per page in your menu.

For example :

```
const items = this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
  .map(({ node }) => { 
    return (
      <li>{ node.data.you.want }</li>
    )
 })
```

You can now put `items` in your menu to see a `li` for each page.